# EAS build error when adding react-native-image-filter-kit

Tags: android, react-native, expo, imagefilter, eas

I am trying to implement image filters with react-native-image-filter-kit.
I follow the implementation steps for with react-native >=0.64.0 from [here](https://github.com/iyegoroff/react-native-image-filter-kit) .

I use EAS build. When i try to build a new apk i get the error below:

```
/home/expo/Android/Sdk/build-tools/29.0.2/llvm-rs-cc: error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

In the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66578908/task-react-native-image-filter-kitcompiledebugrenderscript-failed/67836228#67836228?newreg=809e79a4732a471d84d048d1d2163823) i see that i need to do the following:

> or 32-bit binaries : sudo apt-get install libncurses5:i386

> for 64-bit binaries : sudo apt-get install libncurses5

> Also install the collection of libraries by using this command,

> sudo apt-get install ia32-libs

How can i do that with a managed EAS flow?

Comment: Hi,
Did you manage to find an answer?

Comment: @RobinBobin I found a way to run a script and also I have upgraded to the latest sdk version, but keep getting errors. Have you used react-native-image-filter-kit with EAS as well?

Comment: No, I'm trying to use `expo-pixi`. Actually, what I need to do is copy the behavior of css filters.

Answer (score 0):

EAS incudes scope to run script which will pre-install items that are needed for the build to complete.

So for Expo you do that by adding the 'eas-build...' line to your package.json file

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "eas-build-pre-install": "./pre-install",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
```

You then add the following code in the root of the project in a file called 'pre-install':

```
#!/bin/bash

# This is a file called "pre-install" in the root of the project

if [[ "$EAS_BUILD_PLATFORM" == "android" ]]; then
  echo "Run commands for Android builds here"
  sudo apt-get --quiet update --yes

  sudo apt-get --quiet install --yes \
      libncurses5 \

elif [[ "$EAS_BUILD_PLATFORM" == "ios" ]]; then
  echo "Run commands for iOS builds here"
fi
```

And that's it, the project should be buildable on Android again.

Comment: Thanks, worked for me, just had to give pre-install file-permissions 777 then it worked like a charm